# Google Plus login gives error code 10 in signed ionic app

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, google-plus, google-signin

I'm developing an `ionic` application using `google plus` login. it was properly work when in developing. but in signed apk its give me error 10.
my code is below

```
      window.plugins.googleplus.login({
            scopes: 'profile', 
            webClientId: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            offline: true 
      },function (user_data) {
        console.log(user_data)
      },function (msg) {
           alert(msg);
      });
```

I have generated a new `SHA1` key and `WebclientId` by using `realese keystore`.
I think this is a `SHA1` key problem, but i'm not get solution yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure you are saving your SHA-1 fingerprint (for debug and for release mode) on firebase 
[image]

I had this issue for days, my app was working fine when deployed to the device from the PC, in debug and release mode, login started falling when I published my app to the Android store, and install it from there, the problem was that the app signing was selected by default when you publish…
[image]
In order to fix this you have to get your SHA-1 fingerprint from the android developer console and add it to the firebase console…
[image: appsigningappsigning.png851x399 50.4 KB]
I’ve created a blog post explaining it in details here
http://www.jomendez.com/2017/08/30/ionic-2-google-sign-in-error-10-with-firebase/

Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: I tested this solution in March 2020 and it works PERFECT! Thanks a ton for sharing!!!

Comment: Good gravy I wish I could upvote this a million times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have used different keystore for both process.

1. Generating SHA key.
2. For signing apk.

now the solution is.
we should have to used same keystore for both process.

1. Generating SHA key.
2. For signing apk.

its worked for me. I hope its also work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I had glazed over this article as I was using android studio and not firebase so I never read it (wish I had). It was the same problem and solution as it relates registering the correct sha1 key from google play portal. Being new to android I opted in for google play app signing but was using my local release keystore sha1 and figured out the mistake after a day.

Comment: And how does that answer the question?

Comment: There was not much help on the topic for error code 10 as it related to only happening for one build type but working fine for debug builds. All the articles for it are about it not working period regardless of build type.  I think google play signing is fairly new and only newbies to android would probably opt in to use it so that maybe why there isn't anything out there on it yet other than this one here. It is a pretty easy mistake to do.