# error code 10 with ionic 4 and google native sign in

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been reading and reading and pouring over many different articles on how to resolve it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756378/google-plus-login-gives-error-code-10-in-signed-ionic-app) [this](http://www.jomendez.com/2017/08/30/ionic-2-google-sign-in-error-10-with-firebase/) [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243) [don't forget this one](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360)

I have a firebase account already with a pre existing 0auth set up, however, I have opted to create a new authentication for android. here is what I have done

1. create the new app in firebase let's call it "androidAuth"
2. get the google-services.json file and place it within the project's root directory
3. in termanal run `$ keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystone` enter password "android.
4. copy the SHA1 fingerprint
5. go back to firebase click the button that says "add fingerprint"
6. paste fingerprint in there.
7. run the application on my android device
8. click google sign in, the prompt for emails come up
9. 'error --> 10'

here is the code, pretty simple:

```js
public loginGoogle(): void {
    this.google
        .login({})
        .then((res: any): void => {
            console.log('res -->', res);
        })
        .catch((e: ErrorEvent): void => console.log('error -->', e));
}
```

thanks for any help on this.
*update* I've created a local keystore that is saved in the apps root folder, i added that to the firebase fingerprint list, still error 10